# How to locate & run a specific function on a website using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I would like to know what runs a specific Javascript function on a website - and I would like to trigger them manually using the console.

However, sometimes the websites's Javascript is having a lot of objects-inside-objects and I'm having trouble locating what runs a specific function - and - triggering them manually.

I believe learning this will give me a lot of know-how in terms of debugging certain things on built websites, to understand more about how certain things are built.

Comment: Your question seems to be regarding reverse engineering a website. Question for clarification: am I right that you want to click elements, move the mouse or press keys and stop at a line of code that is handling the event? Or do you want to stop at the line of code that is about to remove or alter an element? Is this what you want, or something else? Note that many websites may have "ugylified" code that, even when de-uglyfying using the dev tools, may be hard to read and understand.

Comment: @try-catch-finallyyou are correct, this is about reverse engineering a website and understanding how certain things work.

Comment: @try-catch-finally I've already located the functions in that "uglified" code, I just can't trigger them manually, I'm looking for a way to understand how/if this would be possible.

Comment: If you've located the function creating a break point inside that function and triggering it would reveal the "call path" in the _stack panel_. Have you tried using break points? Please add the steps and approaches you've already tried to isolate how functions are called. When you say you've identified a function, how have you done that? Note: at this point your question is quite broad and I'd like to make it focus on a certain topic, else it might get too broad or even misleading answers.

Comment: Didn't you ask that question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714644/developer-tools-find-object-runtime)?

Comment: @try-catch-finally it would be nice to work with breakpoints but the code is minified, therefore, breakpoint is always at line 1.. I'm not sure if it's possible to deal with these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tiny recipe for that may help getting started with reverse engineering a website using the developer tools.

**Pretty print minified code:**

To be able to set break points and step through code

[image: Chrome Dev Tools: pretty print minified code]

---

**Set a breakpoint at a known function:**

To stop execution and be able to inspect the call stack in the panel on the right hand side (to in turn isolate the trigger).

[image: Chrome Dev Tools: set break point at known function]

---

**Break on the handler of a certain DOM event:**

To isolate the function being executed on certain interactions/events.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools: break on DOM events]

---

**Break on code that modifies the DOM:**

That is adding or removing sub tree nodes for example.

To isolate code that is modifing the DOM during render.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools: break on the code that modifies the DOM]

---

**Break on the next execution:**

If there's periodic code running and/or you can't get a handle on code execution through the other methods.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools: break on next execution]

---

Note that the step do not cover all the possible functions to debug and reverse engineer code on a website. Other functions are, for example: XHR breakpoints or the profiler.

The developers constantly add and change functions in the dev tools. Play around with them and test them out.

---

Screenshots were taken debugging youtube.com

Comment: @Mia: I've added an answer that is as broad as your question. Don't alter your original question to make it more specific (after gaining some knowledge from my answer) nor ask for details how to do things on certain steps in the comments. If this answer was not helpful enough, please ask a new question with a _specific_ and _reproducible_ problem description and all steps you've done trying to get to a solution.